# Traversing TD elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to traverse through `<td>` elements to get the sibling radio boxes so that only one image can be selected at a time (I'm using the following example but added inputs into a table for formatting purposes http://jsfiddle.net/yijiang/Zgh24/1/):

HTML:

```
<div id="divid">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="test1" id="test1" value="1" /><label>IMAGE</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="test2" id="test2" value="4" /><label>IMAGE</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('#divid input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');
$('#divid label').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to traverse correctly to ensure only one image can be selected at a time within the `<td>` elements - I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
$(this).addClass('selected').parent('td').find('label').removeClass('selected');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of using `input type="radio"` not to have multiple selections? Standard inputs with the same `name` attribute will never collide with each other (at least, in browsers that follow the spec).

Comment: Yes, radio will exclude each other as long as they have the same name, but he needs that effect to reflect also on the image.

Comment: If I remove the table formatting, .siblings works - it adds the class and removes the class like in the jsFiddle example - but when I added the radio box inputs into a table, I can select more than one radio input at a time - I need to only select one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the class `.selected` from the `label` elements which is being set with `.selected` class and then add `.selected` class to the current element,

```
$('#divid label').click(function(){
  $('label.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: +1 I got a little too long winded trying to show the traversal :-/

Answer (score 0):

Your radio inputs have different names. That means they can be selected at the same time, since they're DIFFERENT radio buttons. If you had

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="2" />
```

Then the browser would automatically deselect one when the other is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do something like this is to remove the class from all elements, and then add it to the one you need it added to.

So something like this should work:

```
$('.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle it is just a matter of choosing the right siblings - http://jsfiddle.net/Zgh24/1248/

```
$('#sites label').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('label').removeClass('selected');
});
```

For your table example above you have to approach it a little differently, because doing it all in one chained group causes the selected item to have the class removed as well.

```
$('#divid label').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('label').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zgh24/1249/